# QCombobox set the width to fit grid layout column

Tags: qt, pyqt5

I am working in PyQt (Can understand also Qt answers)
I have a dialog.
In my dialog I have a grid.
In one of the grid columns I have QComboBox
I want the width of the QComboBox to change to the size of the grid column (in the same way that QLineEdit does)
Also is there a place that explains all the size policies and layout handeling of Qt

[image]
Thanks,
Ilan

The following is a minimal working example
1. The Ui_ParametersDialog was generated using the Qt Designer
2. The parametersDialog has a model which contains a list of Parameters
3. Each Parameter is actually an OrderedDict
4. The Parameters are inserted to the dialog using a static method in the   ParametersInput Class
5. The fact that nothing is written for setting the ComboBox size does not meen that I did not try.
[image]

The Code:

[files](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1se1-KE46uzBsfEZMdRHo6FGhwlcp4YL7?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please provide an [mcve].

Comment: Share your arcgivo .ui and .py

Comment: all the .py you nee are found (The automatically generated file is the Ui_ParametersDialog.py). I added the .ui file even though it is not needed to activate the application. to activate the application use python ParametersDialog.py